# Updating (or using) Arcgis 9 Extension to Arcgis 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, extensions

i am a noob learning arcgis, I want to use the following extension [Generating and Updating Ordinary and Multiplicatively Weighted Voronoi Diagrams for Points, Lines, and Polygon](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15481)s built for arcgis 9 in arcgis 10.1.  How do i do that?

Comment: If there is not a later version of that extension available, then I think you should try installing the version built for 9.x with 10.1. I think there is a chance that it will just work but if it does not then maybe it will give you some information to debug/upgrade it.

Comment: arcgis 10.1 does not recognize this extension. i think i will try what @Jakub suggested

Comment: Alternatively, you could try contacting the author of that tool, who may already have a suitable version, or be in a position to quickly create one.

Comment: am having the same issue and just wondering if you were able to get the extension to run in 10.1
Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/80481)

Answer (score 1):

Version 9 extensions have to be converted, updated, possibly re-written in parts and recompiled for version 10. The method extensions are deployed has changed fundamentally between these 2 versions of ArcGIS. (as well as new SDK, new version of Visual Studio .Net, etc.)
You may try what @PolyGeo have suggested but it may not work. (version 8 would have worked in version 9 and version 10 in 10.3 but version 9 will likely not work in version 10)